# Do I have to follow a formula to write good fiction?

Tags: fiction, formula, principles

When writing fiction, do I need to follow a formula or can I author a story the way I see fit?

Answer (score 1):

**You can write your story anyway you see fit. It's your story.**

that doesn't mean anyone else will like the story when you are done.

There are lots of resources on the art of storytelling that can provide a sort of framework for you. Google will show a great many of them and you can pick which one best helps you. Or you can just wing it.

In the end, how you tell your stories is based on you and how you relate to the world. Use whatever method works and makes it easiest for you to finish your story.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

You can do anything you want, and if you write well, readers may like it. On the other hand there are genre conventions that lead readers to expect certain things. If you break them they may be disappointed.

So experiment and learn what works for you.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary. If you follow a formula, you're likely to write okay fiction. Not bad, but also not particularly interesting.

That isn't to say you should completely ignore formulas, it can be very rewarding to sort of follow them but just not quite. And if you're a beginner, a formula can help you avoid some of the common mistakes (e. g. "too much worldbuilding, not enough story").

But the really good fiction isn't generally written by obediently following a formula.

Let the story itself tell you where it needs to go. Everything else, formulas included, is a tool at your disposition that may or may not come in handy for the task. Feel free to use it or not.

Every genre has its conventions and it tends to lead to better results if you break them intentionally with a clear reason, than if you break them simply because you don't understand them or can't be bothered to care. But the fact that you *can* break them (though probably not all in one work) is the cornerstone of creativity.

Answer (score 0):

**No. You do not need to follow a formula in order to write fiction.**

However, there are certain "Rules" of fiction that it is best practices to follow. No one has to, but the people who do are usually the ones who people like to read. Most of the rules you can naturally pick up by just reading, but if you're nervous about starting, you can always review them. (I do it from time to time)

If you're looking for a good series to teach fiction best practices, I highly recommend. Brandon Sanderson's college lecture series on creative writing. He has put his series on the internet and you can find it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cf-qdZ7GbA&list=PLSH_xM-KC3Zv-79sVZTTj-YA6IAqh8qeQ